# How to Reset the Order ID in magento 2 Multi store view

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have multiview in Magento 2 website, I want to reset the order id and I have to change the starting number of the order id. (ex: 100000100)

Please help to resolve the issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your PHP Admin database
2. Find & click on the table called: sequence_order_1 (it is located in the database itself, not in the information_schema )
3. Click on the "Operations" tab & under the "AUTO_INCREMENT" edit to the desired order number.